# KeyNotFoundException when trying to access mocked object in dictionary

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

My mock test is throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`:

```
[Fact]
public void MockAssembly_GetTypes_ReturnsMockedTypes()
{
    var mockAssembly = new Mock<Assembly>();

    mockAssembly.Setup(a => a.GetTypes()).Returns(new Type[] { typeof(MyClass) });
    var mockAssemblyObject = mockAssembly.Object;

    var assemblyDictionary = new Dictionary<Assembly, HashSet<Type>>();
    if (!assemblyDictionary.TryGetValue(mockAssemblyObject, out var types))
    {
        types = new HashSet<Type>(mockAssemblyObject.GetTypes());
        assemblyDictionary[mockAssemblyObject] = types;
    }

    Assert.Contains(mockAssemblyObject, assemblyDictionary.Keys);
    Assert.Single(assemblyDictionary[mockAssemblyObject]);
}
```

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '' was not present in the dictionary.

On the line `Assert.Single(assemblyDictionary[mockAssemblyObject]);`

Even mocking `GetHashCode` doesn't help - it still tries to use an empty key.

Why is this happening?

Edit:

Further testing shows if I call `assemblyDictionary.TryGetValue(mockAssemblyObject, out var myTypes);` even immediately after I add using `assemblyDictionary.Add(mockAssemblyObject, types)` the result is false and null.

Comment: Is the key in the database?  You created a new dictionary.  Where did you insert values into the database?

Comment: @jdweng `assemblyDictionary[mockAssemblyObject] = types;` I believe does this.

Comment: Try using assemblyDictionary.Add(...

Comment: @Eldar same exception.
When I debug I can see the dictionary contains the added mocked object.

Even when I try another TryGetValue it fails. See my edit.

Comment: A row of a Dictionary contains a KEY and a VALUE.  You mockAssemblyObject does not have a KEY and VALUE.

Comment: @jdweng How then, can I mock the key of my mock? I was always under the impression that behind the scenes Dictionary will use the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` of the class to determine its key and comparisons with other keys. My value, a list of types is successfully being mocked and added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `CallBase` to `true`:

```
var mockAssembly = new Mock<Assembly>() { CallBase = true };
```

Both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are also virtual methods, and unless you set `CallBase` to `true`, Moq will also override these methods with 'mock' implementations.

It's not quite obvious that this fixes the problem, but in my repro of the OP, it does. The test now passes.

Comment: Can verify this fixes the problem! Thank you for the answer this was very puzzling for me :)